# MDX Repeat Measure betwewn Start Date and End Date

Tags: ssas, mdx

Think about following Facttable:

```
 customer  | StartDate  | EndDate     | FeePerDay | FeeDayDuration
      A    | 01.01.2015 | 03.01.5015  | 10        |  3
```

Is it possible to create a calculated Measure which will Repeat "FeePerDay" until EndDate is reached. 
If I create an `MDX` expression like (this is pseudo MDX):

```
Select 
   { FeePerDay } on 0,
   {[Customer].[A]} 
   *{ [Date].[31.12.2014] : [Date].[06.01.2015] } on 1,
From Cube
```

The result should be like following table:

```
 customer | Date         | ValuePerDay
    A     | 31.12.2014   | NULL
    A     | 01.01.2015   | 10
    A     | 02.01.2015   | 10
    A     | 03.01.2015   | 10
    A     | 04.01.2015   | NULL
    A     | 05.01.2015   | NULL
    A     | 06.01.2015   | NULL
```

Comment: Can you caluculate it in data source or in data source view? It is the easiest way to achieve something like this.

Comment: 1. When you say repeat the measure, you mean for that customer? 2. In the example, the measure repeats *beyond* the end date(i.e. on 04th too the value is 10, while it should be NULL.

Comment: Thx SouravA, the 04th must be NULL.
And Yes, the Measure should be repeated for the assigned Customer A

Comment: @AdrianChodkowski: My first try was, to calculate it via view, this works for fine for small Facttables. 
In our case the result of the view would create multiple billion of rows, so the view perfomance is very bad. Than the Cube prozessing is bad, i have to use ROLAP and so on... I have to find a other solution :-)

Comment: What should be the fee total for customer A for all of January? 310? Null? 10? Just wondering how it aggregates.

Comment: @GregGalloway for January total fee should be 30.

Comment: @mamba can you explain your math?

Comment: @GregGalloway  the calculated measure should create the table mentioned above. So then the math should be "sum(ValuePerDay)".

Comment: Ah. I see. ValuePerDay is really value per month (or at least there is only one day per month in your example). If you didn't want data to aggregate over days you could use a many-to-many Date dimension. But that won't make the data aggregate. So I really must say your initial approach of creating a view is correct. You just need to bite the bullet and purchase adequate hardware to handle billions of rows. Billions of rows are possible in SSAS If you do it right. The other alternative is crappy query performance with some terribly slow MDX at the leaf level. It will be unusable with MDX

Comment: Greg, how would it be if we create a cube member using SCOPE statement, since it will be handled at processing time? That's one option we have not considered yet. Just curious.

Comment: @mamba - just saw the comments. Isn't MOLAP/HOLAP an option? ROLAP is needed only if you need real time data.

Comment: @SouravA i have used ROLAP because of memory limitation. 
Isnt it possible to create such a calculated Measure? Cant imagine that this is not possible ;-) , but i am struggling with the MDX.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can give this a shot.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.ValuePerDay AS
IIF(
    DateDiff(
            "d", 
            EXISTS([Customer].[StartDate].MEMBERS, ([Customer].CurrentMember, FeePerDay)).Item(0), 
            [Date].CurrentMember
            ) <=0
    and
    DateDiff(
            "d", 
            [Date].CurrentMember, 
            EXISTS([Customer].[EndDate].MEMBERS, ([Customer].CurrentMember, FeePerDay)).Item(0)
            ) <=0
    ,
    FeePerDay 
    ,
    NULL
   )

SELECT {[Customer].Members} 
*
{ [Date].[31.12.2014] : [Date].[06.01.2015] } ON 1,
ValuePerDay ON 0
FROM [Cube]
```